# How to upload a file using RestClient in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am trying to upload a file in Ruby. Below is a sample of the REST call using curl.

```
curl --sslv3 -k -v -i -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Cookie: token=ABC; SESSION=13217EBA128F6ABC9E9AD095D602E4AB;" \
-F "metadata=@input_payload_file.json; type=application/json" \
-F "content=@MyFile.jpg; type=image/jpg"  \
https://abc.com/attachments.
```

Can some please give me an equivalent of above in Ruby.
I have tried the following, with no success.

```
$fileitem = File.new('C:\log.txt', 'rb');
$fileinfo = '{"fileName":"log.txt", "resourceName":"log.txt",  "description":"Created using REST"}';

response =RestClient::Request.execute(
   :method => :post,
   :url => $UploadURL,
   :headers => {:content_type => 'multipart/mixed', :accept => 'application/json'},
   :cookies => {:token=> :"#{cust}",:SESSIONID => :"#{ssid}"},
   :payload => $fileinfo,
   :myfile => $fileitem
)
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Ravi..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using the `--sslv3` flag? I'm pretty sure SSLv3 is dead-in-the-water, Considered-Harmful, deprecated technology. Anyone may feel to correct me if I'm wrong; I'd be glad to be corrected.

Comment: Don't use `$global` variables unless you understand why you should use them. As is, in this code they are code-smell and show you don't understand variable scoping. Also, Ruby doesn't need backslashes for Windows paths. See the [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html) documentation.

Comment: Also, consider using the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem. It's a closer match to cURL.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, Will explore Curb gem. I agree with not using global variables, I am relatively new to Ruby, The code I trying is just a single script like code where I am trying to upload files using REST calls.

Comment: Hi Jesse, --sslv3 sample code was provided by the application API provider. I believe it is now changed to tslv1. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the code working. Cleared up the smelly code.
Below is the syntax that worked well while posting a multipart/mixed mode data.

```
response =RestClient::Request.execute(
   :method => :post,
   :url => uploadURL,
   :headers => {:content_type => 'multipart/mixed', :accept => 'application/json'},
   :cookies => {:token => cust,:SESSIONID => ssid },
   :payload => {:metadata => fileinfo, :content => fileitem, }
)
```