# Passing metadata with payload for Google Drive Rest API

Tags: ruby, rest, google-drive-api, rubygems, rest-client

I have been facing an issue in passing metadata with the Payload using the `google drive api`

I have been trying the following but title, description, etc is not applied to the uploaded file on drive.

```
  upload_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files"
  access_token = "---secret_access_token---"

  fileitem = File.open('<filename>.pptx')
  fileinfo = {"title": "insertedFromApi.pptx", "description": "Test description of file being uploaded from the API"}
  params = {convert: true}
  response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :post,
      :url => upload_url,
      :headers => {"params": params, "uploadType": "multipart", content_type: 'multipart/related', accept: 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token},
      :payload => {:content => fileitem, metadata: {title: 'insertedfromapi.pptx'}}
  )
```

Although the google api says they accept metadata in multipart requests only, I have been doing that still all the files pushed are `UNTITLED`

Example request [given here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads) :-

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "title": "My File"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

JPEG data
--foo_bar_baz--
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you aren't using the `RestClient` correctly. Take a look at this similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117408/how-to-upload-a-file-using-restclient-in-ruby